# How to assign some number to the miners in POW substrate chain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, validator, consensus, block-production

I'm working with POW substrate chain and I want to assign some number to the miners according to the work they have done earlier. Is it possible? If yes can we fetch those numbers during the block production(consensus time)?